# Facebook Share Link Data Extract how to do with asp.net and c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

What i want to do is a user will enter a url into a textbox and like in the facebook i wanna be able to retrieve images in the page, meta keywords, meta description and etc..

Basically i wanna do the Facebook Share Link property with the Asp.net and c#? 
Any thoughts?

Comment: Check this out: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978186/how-to-extract-data-from-url-like-facebook-in-asp-net-mvc3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to new up a `WebClient()` and do an http request and then parse out what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.80).aspx

```
string html = string.Empty;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("user-agent",
        "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
    using (Stream data = client.OpenRead("http://someurl.com"))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data))
    {
        html = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```