# How to fetch url data in asp.net mvc3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I want to extract/fetch url data in my asp.net mvc3 application. How can i ectract url data. Its like facebook does in wall post.

http://www.9lessons.info/2010/06/facebook-like-extracting-url-data-with.html

How can i do that? any reference or demo available for asp.net mvc3 application?

Comment: This is discussed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978186/how-to-extract-data-from-url-like-facebook-in-asp-net-mvc3

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `WebClient` class to fetch an external page, and the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse it.